# Vector equations in C

Tags: c, function, void

Im trying to code this function which computes the projection formula
P(x) = x + (c- a dot x)a * (1/|a|^2). Note that x and a are vectors and c is a scalar. Also note that a dot x is the product dot/inner product  of a and x. Here is what I have,

```
double dotProduct(double *q, double *b, int length) {
    double runningSum = 0;
    for (int index = 0; index < length; index++)
        runningSum += q[index] * b[index];
    return runningSum;
 }
void project(double *x ,int n, double *a, double c)
{   double m_sum = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        m_sum += a[i]*a[i];
    }
    for ( int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        x[j] = x[j] + (1/ m_sum)* (c - dotProduct(a, x, n))*a[j];
    }
}
```

So my question is how do I create a test file to check the consistency of the project function since it doesn’t return anything. Is my code even right?  does not return anything.

Comment: By printing out `x` after you called the function?

Comment: As Joachim said, pick an initial `x` for which you know the answer, then run your function and print out `x` at the end. By the way, there is a bug in the code as it stands. `dotProduct(a, x, n)` will change value for each iteration in your loop (`x` is changing). You want to use a temp variable before instead (i.e., `double dotP = dotProduct(a, x, n);` before the `for` loop)

Comment: Have you written this code on your own? It looks like you have no idea what it does.

Comment: the function takes an initial simplex and picks an unconctainted intial simplex R^n and projects it onto the range space of a matrix.  The code above is a special case when A is 1 by n @FUZxxl

Comment: @TimothyBrown I was wondering because you are confused about `project` not returning a result. If you wrote that code, surely you know why `project` does not return a result?

Comment: The first `for` loop could be replaced with `double m_sum = dotProduct(a, a, n);`